# Secure way of saving a password in a Outook Web-Add-In

Tags: javascript, security, outlook-addin

I am just developing a Web-Add-In for Outlook 2016. I would like to save username and password, so the user does not need to fill in this data every time.

How can you realize this in a secure way with JavaScript? Code Snippets are welcome.

Comment: Would be great if you could post something that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to separate your question into two as follow ...

> I would like to save **username**, so the user does not need to fill in this data every time.

There is very convenient object in Office.js API: `RoamingSettings`. The settings created by using the methods of the RoamingSettings object are saved per add-in and per user. That is, they are available only to the add-in that created them, and only from the user's mail box in which they are saved. Basically **username** is the perfect candidate to be stored in this object.

> I would like to save **password**, so the user does not need to fill in this data every time.

The `RoamingSettings` object should not be used for the **passwords**, tokens and other authentication data. Documentation clearly stated the following ...

*While the Outlook Add-in API limits access to these settings to only the add-in that created them, these settings should not be considered secure storage. They can be accessed by Exchange Web Services or Extended MAPI. They should not be used to store sensitive information such as user credentials or security tokens.*

As the common sense, storing user password into insecure store is bad idea. Even storing hash of the password is not that great as JavaScript code is very exposed to the client and user password may be subject to dictionary attack as you will not be able to hide your salting / peppering with JS.  The user should authorize to your service (add-in) every time. Bottom line: DO NOT store the user password insecurely in the mailbox.